# Convert image into tiles with xyz url (open layers)

Tags: image, maps, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a png image that I want to use with leaflet. How can I turn the url pf the image so it can be used with `TileLayer`?

```
  <TileLayer
    url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
  />
```

How can I make it so I use it with the `{z}/{x}/{y}.png`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I just learned most of this stuff myself. This may not be best practices for such a thing, but it worked for my needs.

---

If you have an *image* you want to make into a map, you can chop it up with a Python script (with Pillow) and put it into a directory structure described by `{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, where each image is 256x256 pixels (I've heard you can have different sizes but let's just go with the default) and then put it behind a normal static file web server. The top level directory will represent each zoom level, the next level directory will represent the `x` location of the tile, and the file name `{y}.png` will represent the `y` location.

## URL/Directory Structure

How many `x`'s and `y` values are there? That depends on the zoom level. See here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

It starts out with zoom level 0, where one image (tile) represents the entire world. At each subsequent zoom level, each tile gets split into four quadrants. There are twice as many `x` and `y` values, and thus 4 times as many tiles. So zoom level 1 is 2x2 images, zoom level 2 is 4x4 images, and so on.

So let's say you're storing it in:

`/var/www/tiles/`

Your files for the first 3 zoom levels will look like this:

```
/var/www/tiles/0
/var/www/tiles/0/0
/var/www/tiles/0/0/0.png
/var/www/tiles/1
/var/www/tiles/1/0
/var/www/tiles/1/0/0.png
/var/www/tiles/1/0/1.png
/var/www/tiles/1/1
/var/www/tiles/1/1/0.png
/var/www/tiles/1/1/1.png
/var/www/tiles/2
/var/www/tiles/2/0
/var/www/tiles/2/0/3.png
/var/www/tiles/2/0/0.png
/var/www/tiles/2/0/1.png
/var/www/tiles/2/0/2.png
/var/www/tiles/2/3
/var/www/tiles/2/3/3.png
/var/www/tiles/2/3/0.png
/var/www/tiles/2/3/1.png
/var/www/tiles/2/3/2.png
/var/www/tiles/2/1
/var/www/tiles/2/1/3.png
/var/www/tiles/2/1/0.png
/var/www/tiles/2/1/1.png
/var/www/tiles/2/1/2.png
/var/www/tiles/2/2
/var/www/tiles/2/2/3.png
/var/www/tiles/2/2/0.png
/var/www/tiles/2/2/1.png
/var/www/tiles/2/2/2.png
```

And of course it explodes from there.

Put all of this inside your static file serving directory, and set the `url` for the tile layer such that it maps to the URLs (based on the directory structure) of your files given `x`, `y`, and `z`. So something like `https://mysite.example.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

## Choosing / Preparing your image

Assuming your image is of the planet Earth, you'll want to find an image of world map in the correct *projection*. The world is, by most accounts, round, whereas maps are flat. There are different ways, known as projections, of contorting the round earth into a flat map. The projection that OSM uses is called Pseudo-Mercator or Web Mercator. See here if you're curious, but the details here are not important: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection

You'll want your image to be in this projection. And even then, you'll want it lined up correctly. Though, I found one online that was already lined up, perhaps that's standard. If you're making the image yourself, that may be harder. But perhaps you can find a Web Mercator world map as a guide.

To find out whether it's lined up, you can import a geojson outline of all of the countries into your Leaflet application to see if it lines up. I won't go into that here, but you can look it up.

## Chopping up your image:

So how do we actually get the right images in the right place? We can chop up the source image with a Python script using Pillow (a fork of the defunct Python Imaging Library).

We basically want a loop that goes through each zoom level, and then under that for each x and y. The number of `x`'s (and `y`'s) doubles each zoom level, starting at `1` for `z` of `0`. That means there `2^z` values of `x` and `y` for each `z`.

At each zoom level, the size of each image that we crop out is half as wide and half as long as the previous zoom level. But, we resize it to 256 pixels. This means that you should have a really high quality source image or you'll start to get fuzzy as you zoom in.

I wrote a python script I can share with you (call it MIT license). However, it has some limitations. Perhaps someone more familiar with Pillow can improve on it. This will create a subdirectory under the one holding the script, and put the tiles in there:

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
from PIL import Image

# make sure we can run this script from wherever and not screw up our paths
base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# where we get our image that we chop up
tile_source_path = os.path.join(base_path, "tile-source.png")

# where we put our chopped up images
tile_gen_path = os.path.join(base_path, "static/tiles")

MIN_ZOOM = 4
MAX_ZOOM = 7

TILE_SIZE = 256 # width and height of each tile

with Image.open(tile_source_path) as orig_world_map:
    for z in range(MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM + 1):
        if z == 0:
            print ("Zoom level", z, "- Generating", 2 ** z * 2 ** z, "256x256 image")
        else:
            print ("Zoom level", z, "- Generating", 2 ** z * 2 ** z, "256x256 images")

        tiles_per_dimension = 2 ** z
        # Zoom the world map to be big enough for the number of tiles given the size of the tiles
        zoomed_world_map = orig_world_map.resize((
            tiles_per_dimension * TILE_SIZE,
            tiles_per_dimension * TILE_SIZE,
        ))
        for x in range(tiles_per_dimension):
            # Make the dir representing this value of x, within the dir
            # representing the zoom level z. Values of y are represented
            # by the files within this dir:
            # /tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
            x_val_dir = os.path.join(tile_gen_path, str(z), str(x))
            if not os.path.exists(x_val_dir):
                os.makedirs(x_val_dir)
            for y in range(tiles_per_dimension):
                cropped = zoomed_world_map.crop((
                    x * TILE_SIZE,
                    y * TILE_SIZE,
                    (x + 1) * TILE_SIZE - 1,
                    (y + 1) * TILE_SIZE - 1,
                ))
                cropped.save(os.path.join(x_val_dir, str(y) + ".png"))
```

You may notice that at each zoom level, I first resize the source image to be big enough that each tile is already 256x256 pixels. This means that by zoom level 7 (the furthest I go here) it's a gigapixel image (if I'm calculating correctly). I actually tried zoom 8 (4 gigapixel) before and my laptop couldn't handle it. I was able to do zoom level 8 by renting server space with a lot of memory.

There's an alternate way of doing it that doesn't have this problem: Instead of resizing the source image and cropping it, you can leave the source image as-is and resize the necessary cropped out portion of the image in each iteration. That portion will get smaller and smaller at each zoom level, but they'll always blow up to 256x256. With this method, you probably want to start with an image with dimensions that are a power of two, since you'll be dividing by two over and over. The big problem with this method is that everything ends up looking blocky. This is probably because of the way the compression works. Each sub-image is figured out independently, not in context of their surroundings. But, it's worth throwing out there. Here's how it looks (MIT License):

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
from PIL import Image

# make sure we can run this script from wherever and not screw up our paths
base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# where we get our image that we chop up
tile_source_path = os.path.join(base_path, "tile-source.png")

# where we put our chopped up images
tile_gen_path = os.path.join(base_path, "static/tiles")

MIN_ZOOM = 4
MAX_ZOOM = 7

with Image.open(tile_source_path) as orig:
    for z in range(MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM + 1):
        if z == 0:
            print ("Zoom level", z, "- Generating", 2 ** z * 2 ** z, "256x256 image")
        else:
            print ("Zoom level", z, "- Generating", 2 ** z * 2 ** z, "256x256 images")
        for x in range(2 ** z):
            # Make the dir representing this value of x, within the dir
            # representing the zoom level z. Values of y are represented
            # by the files within this dir:
            # /tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
            x_val_dir = os.path.join(tile_gen_path, str(z), str(x))
            if not os.path.exists(x_val_dir):
                os.makedirs(x_val_dir)
            for y in range(2 ** z):
                max_val = 1024
                size = 1024 * (2 ** (-z))
                assert size == int(size)
                size = int(size)
                resized = orig.resize(
                    (256, 256),
                    box=(
                        x * size,
                        y * size,
                        (x + 1) * size - 1,
                        (y + 1) * size - 1,
                    )
                )
                resized.save(os.path.join(x_val_dir, str(y) + ".png"))
```

I've run these successfully on Linux. A friend tried the first one on Mac and it ended up rather pixelated. Maybe he had an old version of Pillow. Anyway, YMMV. Play around with it, maybe try different "resampling" method for resizing, see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Use a map tiler utility, e.g. http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html or https://www.maptiler.com/

Other solutions are also possible, such as setting up a local instance of mapserver/geoserver, seeding an instance of GeoWebCache and then copying off the files. Or https://mapproxy.org/. Or http://tilecache.org/.

See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/ for more Q&A regarding these tools, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdal2tiles